# Finding part of an image inside another image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I'm relatively new to Matlab and I'm trying to find a part of an image inside of another image, but not just a simple cropped part that I could normally find with `normxcorr2`.

Specifically, I am given a cropped-out body with a black background in 2-dimensional grayscale jpg and I have to find where it comes from in the source image (also a 2-d gray jpg).

I am required to use segmentation and thresholding to obtain the "important features" of the cropped out body, which I have done and this is the result (with default thresholding levels), which saves in the exact same format as before.

[image: segmented image]

What I have tried:
The version of Matlab I have available to me only includes the Image Processing Toolbox, and that is all I am allowed to use in terms of toolboxes (no Computer Vision Toolbox). I have tried is using OpenSURF for feature matching, and this was the result:

[image: result image]

The result is less than favourable. Is there any other way I can accomplish this? Please keep in mind that I am new to image processing and Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, please try the [Object Detection in a Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html) example.